# Can I use the value Bob from a URL like domain.com/user/Bob?

Tags: php

I've been wondering how to get a value from the URL of a website using PHP. I'm new to PHP so please explain in as much detail as you can :)

For example... I believe YouTube uses $_GET['v'] to get the video ID from the URL and then just find the record with that ID and echo out the information onto the page.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWERTYUIOPA
```

Although, the bit I'm curious about is how do I get the value from a normal looking URL which is basically just a folder name.

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/QWERTYUIOPA
```

How would I get the value 'QWERTYUIOPA' from the URL using PHP?

I've searched Google for this but I struggled to find anything because I didn't exactly know what to search. Any links would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Pretty URLs' like the one you've described are nothing more than a little bit of .htaccess / mod_rewrite trickery.

.htaccess is a file that is read and evaluated by the server on each page request, and mod_rewrite is one of the modules that can be loaded into the server.

What happens is when the user requests a page, like http://www.youtube.com/user/QWERTYUIOPA, the server receives the request and reads the .htaccess file.

The requested URL is matched by rules set out in the .htaccess file and is intercepted by the mod_rewrite server module. mod_rewrite then passes the URL to PHP in the format that PHP is expecting.

IE, to the user it looks like

> http://www.youtube.com/user/QWERTYUIOPA

but what the server / mod_rewrite passes to the PHP engine actually looks something like

> http://www.youtube.com/index.php?mode=user&v=QUERYTUIOPA

This looks like a relatively gentle introduction into mod_rewrite so you can get yourself started: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

Neal